# How to add zebra stripe background on div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to alternate row colors with the div tag. My second div is append when user click on add more button

```
<div id="dynamic_field">    
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col s12"  style="padding-top: 12px;">
            <div class="col s12 m12 ">
                <?php if($ViewID!=''){
        $edu_view=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_student_education WHERE studentid= '$v_stduentid' and student_resume_id='$ViewID'");
        while($Get_edu=mysql_fetch_array($edu_view)) {?>
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Certificate Title</label>
                <textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title" name="title[]"><?php echo $Get_edu['degree'];?></textarea>
             </div>
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">School / College, City</label>

                <textarea  id="location" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"><?php echo $Get_edu['location'];?></textarea>
            </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label>
                <input id="marks" name="marks[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $Get_edu['marks'];?>"  />
             </div>
             <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label>
                <input id="divsion" name="divsion[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $Get_edu['division'];?>" placeholder="1st" />
             </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label>
                <input id="year" name="year[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $Get_edu['passing_year'];?>"  />
             </div>
        <?php } } ?>        
                <?php if($EditID!=''){
        $edu_edit=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_student_education WHERE studentid= '$e_stduentid' and student_resume_id='$EditID'");
        while($Get_edu=mysql_fetch_array($edu_edit)) {?>
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Certificate Title</label>
                <textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title" name="title[]"><?php echo $Get_edu['degree'];?></textarea>
             </div>
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">School / College, City</label>

                <textarea  id="location" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"><?php echo $Get_edu['location'];?></textarea>
            </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label>
                <input id="marks" name="marks[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $Get_edu['marks'];?>"  />
             </div>
             <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label>
                <input id="divsion" name="divsion[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $Get_edu['division'];?>" placeholder="1st" />
             </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label>
                <input id="year" name="year[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $Get_edu['passing_year'];?>"  />
             </div>


        <?php } ?>
         <div class="col s3 m3"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add More</button></div>
    <?php   } ?>
                <?php if($ViewID=='' && $EditID==''){?>
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Certificate Title</label>
                <textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title" name="title[]">Higher School Secondary Certificate</textarea>
             </div>
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">School / College, City</label>

                <textarea  id="location" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"></textarea>
            </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label>
                <input id="marks" name="marks[]" type="text" value=""  />
             </div>
             <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label>
                <input id="divsion" name="divsion[]" type="text" value="" placeholder="1st"  />
             </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label>
              <select id="year"  name="year[]">
                <option value="2019" selected>2019</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>

              </select>
             </div>

             <div class="col s3 m3"><button type="button" name="addmoreEdu" id="addmoreEdu" class="btn btn-success pull-right" >Add More</button></div>
             <?php } ?>  
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I did try to add this CSS:

```
#dynamic_field > div:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Issue is that when user click on add more button then background color in the row is not changed. This is my jQuery code where div are appended when click on add more button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=0;  
  $('#addmoreEdu').click(function(){ 
       i++;  
       $('#dynamic_field').append('<div id="row'+i+'"><div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Certificate Title</label><textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title'+i+'" name="title[]">Secondary School Certificate</textarea></div><div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">School / College, City</label><textarea  id="location'+i+'" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"></textarea></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label><input id="marks'+i+'" name="marks[]" type="text" value=""  /></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label><input id="divsion'+i+'" name="divsion[]" type="text" value="" placeholder="1st"  /></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label><select name="year[]"><option value="2019" selected>2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option></select></div><div class="col s3 m3"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger button btn_remove">X</button></div></div>');  
  $('select').material_select('');

$('.btn_remove').click(function(){ 
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });
});
});
```

This is easy to apply zebra stripe on tr tags but I am confused how to apply it on div tags.

Comment: I am not sure how do you mean zebra-stripes but there is an article about stripe css backgrounds here: https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Comment: read this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Comment: I put your code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n70w6h8t/3/) and it works as expected, so can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: First time div background is white when user click on add more button then next div background will grey.. and when user again add more button then third div background is white again

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_striped I want like this way.. it is working on table but I want on divs

Comment: @Hayamkhan When running the fiddle, the existing content is all inside the `row` div, so it is all grey, even though it is supposed to be two blocks. When adding content, the new divs are inserted after the `row` div, so those will have alternating background colors.

Comment: Did you mean `.row > div:nth-of-type(odd)` for a CSS selector?

Comment: see this page https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-of-type

Comment: Just corrected some typo and change a few words to make more sense in the context. zebra stripe in not really a good term but I kept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=0;
        
      $('#addmoreEdu').click(function(){ 
           i++;  
           
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<div class="row"><div id="row'+i+'"><div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Certificate Title</label><textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title'+i+'" name="title[]">Secondary School Certificate</textarea></div><div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">School / College, City</label><textarea  id="location'+i+'" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"></textarea></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label><input id="marks'+i+'" name="marks[]" type="text" value=""  /></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label><input id="divsion'+i+'" name="divsion[]" type="text" value="" placeholder="1st"  /></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label><select name="year[]"><option value="2019" selected>2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option></select></div><div class="col s3 m3"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger button btn_remove">X</button></div></div></div>');  
    
 $('.btn_remove').click(function(){ 
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });
  });
  });
```

```css
#dynamic_field > div:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
 <div id="dynamic_field">  
  <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col s12"  style="padding-top: 12px;">
        <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Certificate Title</label>
           <textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title" name="title[]">Higher School Secondary Certificate</textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">School / College, City</label>
         
           <textarea  id="location" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"></textarea>
       </div>
           <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label>
           <input id="marks" name="marks[]" type="text" value=""  />
          </div>
          <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label>
           <input id="divsion" name="divsion[]" type="text" value="" placeholder="1st"  />
          </div>
           <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label>
           <select id="year"  name="year[]">
            <option value="2019" selected>2019</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>     
           </select>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col s3 m3"><button type="button" name="addmoreEdu" id="addmoreEdu" class="btn btn-success pull-right" >Add More</button></div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Now this is working perfectly as I expected.. I was some changing in my divs then show it zebra stripe on divs